# Seemingly empty .cpp file in CodeBlocks?

Tags: character-encoding, codeblocks

I have a ~2kb .cpp file I created in CodeBlocks on a different computer, with some code that compiles and runs no problem. However, whenever I try to open it in CodeBlocks on my own computer, it looks as-if it's completely empty. It's not - it still compiles and runs on this device (though the result is somewhat different from what it should be), and I can still see the code when I open it with Notepad++.

I suspect the issue might be related to language encoding, as that code contains quite a few characters specific to central/eastern European languages (that part is non-negotiable as it is a part of my assignment to deal with various encodings, I cannot simply remove them). Whenever I open the file on my own computer in Notepad++, instead of the specific characters I put in, I see scrambled garbage (it was fine on the other computer).

I tried opening the file in Notepad++, changing its encoding, and copying the code into a new empty CodeBlocks file, but then I get this error:

```
error: narrowing conversion of '50309' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|
```

Which I'd guess could be due to the character being interpreted as encoded in UTF-8 or something...?